# I can't read from a UART/Nios

Tags: c, vhdl, fpga, nios

I've included an UART component to my FPGA, and I've written this sample code to out a character(I want to test if its working) :

```
  #include <alt_types.h>
#include <altera_avalon_pio_regs.h>
#include <altera_avalon_uart_regs.h>
#include <sys/alt_irq.h>
#include <sys/alt_alarm.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "system.h"

int main(void)
{
int filed;
int x=0;
unsigned char c=5;
filed = open ("dev/uart_0", O_RDWR| O_NOCTTY );
while (x<10){
write (filed, &c,1);
x++;
}

}
```

I'm using **realterm** to read the output, but nothing appears, any help ?
thx

Comment: Uart is a hardware component, it needs time to transfer stuff, but you are not leaving it any. Anyway, working with NIOS both with hardware and software is not that simple, the problem can be anywhere down the chain.

Comment: Don't you have to, like, initialize stuff?  Baud rate etc?  Do you have to turn the power on the the UART?  Does the hardware, (cables, connectors etc), work?  We can't fix embedded stuff by blog - you have to do it, on site, with the hardware, debugger, scope, terminal emulator etc etc.

Comment: @EugeneSh. thank you for passing by my question, what you mean by leaving time, should I increase the wile loop (x<1000000)? I've tried the cable (by shorting both input and output) and it worked, also I've tried to send and receive by writing the Tx,Rx my self and it worked, however, when I tried using Nios I got nothing, is the code above wrong/missing some parts?

Comment: @MartinJames hello, I did sit the the Baud rate when I added the UART component in Qsys, I'm not censored to get right answer at the moment, I just want to see an output, will this code give me an output? if not,what should I do?

Comment: By "leaving no time" I meant, that you are attempting to write the UART over and over again, without waiting the previous operation to be complete. But as @MartinJames says, there are lot of stuff to fix before..

Comment: this is how I configure the RX and TX, is it write, or the other way around ?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5PXKMhwKWQRa1NQQ2tPVUVfZVE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: `"dev/uart_0"` is suspicious. Shouldn't is have a leading slash? In any case, check the return value of `open`.

Comment: I believe you are right, I've added an if statement to check whither the statement works or not and it didn't worked, what is the problem? I'll attach some screenshots, please give them a look, you might figure out the problem @user58697
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5PXKMhwKWQRRXRVdnZ6a2dWWkk/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5PXKMhwKWQRREpyZGp4NmU3MzQ/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5PXKMhwKWQRVXFkbFQyZEo3Tnc/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5PXKMhwKWQRZDFGRV92Uk1BZlk/view?usp=sharing
thank you very mush .

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all, I did one modification and every thing worked just fine, instead of writing : `filed = open ("dev/uart_0", O_RDWR| O_NOCTTY );`
I write `filed = open ("dev/uart_0", O_RDWR);`
I don't really why it worked, if someone has an answer please let me know :)